# groovy script for setting the custom field mandatory based on the selection of another custom field

Tags: groovy, jira

We have a custom field named Build_Environment_type, drop-down having values Preprod, Prod, dev and Demo, when Prod is selected, QA Signoff Custom field should be changed to Mandatory and for all the other 3 values, QA Signoff field is not required.

This configuration is created for Create Issue Screen. this functionality can be achieved by using the Script Runner add on which need a groovy snippet, hence looking for the snippet.

Code:

```
def childField = getFieldByName("QA Signoff")
//def parentField = getFieldById(getFieldChanged())
def parentField = getFieldById(getFieldChanged())
def selectedOption = parentField.getValue() as String

if (selectedOption == "Prod")
{
  childField.setRequired(true)
}
else
{
  childField.setRequired(false)
}
```

Error when run on Script Console:

```
No signature of method: 
org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getFieldByName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [QA Signoff]
```

Not sure about import statements for groovy.

Comment: format, details, remove unnecessary info

Comment: @Dinesh: Could you please specify, where you're trying to run this script from? Are you trying to customize JIRA through the `Behaviors` plugin or are you trying to run it from `Script Runner`?